merge(): how to keep both columns defined by.x and by.y in the result
Given the example data in the ?merge man page:
authors <- data.frame(
    ## I(*) : use character columns of names to get sensible sort order
    surname = I(c("Tukey", "Venables", "Tierney", "Ripley", "McNeil")),
    nationality = c("US", "Australia", "US", "UK", "Australia"),
    deceased = c("yes", rep("no", 4)))
authorN <- within(authors, { name <- surname; rm(surname) })
books <- data.frame(
    name = I(c("Tukey", "Venables", "Tierney",
             "Ripley", "Ripley", "McNeil", "R Core")),
    title = c("Exploratory Data Analysis",
              "Modern Applied Statistics ...",
              "LISP-STAT",
              "Spatial Statistics", "Stochastic Simulation",
              "Interactive Data Analysis",
              "An Introduction to R"),
    other.author = c(NA, "Ripley", NA, NA, NA, NA,
                     "Venables & Smith"))

I do:
m <- merge(authors, books, by.x = "surname", by.y = "name", all = TRUE)

and get:
> head(authors,3)
   surname nationality deceased
1    Tukey          US      yes
2 Venables   Australia       no
3  Tierney          US       no
> head(books,3)
      name                         title other.author
1    Tukey     Exploratory Data Analysis         <NA>
2 Venables Modern Applied Statistics ...       Ripley
3  Tierney                     LISP-STAT         <NA>
> 
> head(m,3)
  surname nationality deceased                     title     other.author
1  McNeil   Australia       no Interactive Data Analysis             <NA>
2  R Core        <NA>     <NA>      An Introduction to R Venables & Smith
3  Ripley          UK       no        Spatial Statistics             <NA>

Column "name" from books is missing in the output m. Is there any way I could keep it? Among other things, I need to watch for unintentional differences (eg typos) between the "by" variables in my datasets.

You've specified "name" from books and "surrname" from authors as the common columns to join on. Only one is returned ("surrname" in this case since it was specified first.). You could try stringdist_join from the fuzzyjoin package for approximate matching.

It is odd that merge() returns only 1 of the 2 specified key columns. I have solved the issue by adding a name2 variable to books (books$name2 <- books$name), so that I can actually have the information of both key variables in the result.

dplyr join functions default to this behavior as well (which makes sense as a default - usually if a == b you don't need to keep both a and b), but you can set keep = TRUE to keep all the key columns, e.g., dplyr::full_join(authors, books, by = c("surname" = "name"), keep = TRUE)

@user2955884 but name2 is exactly the same as surname, so how does this solve your issue??

@Edward: this is so in the example, but in my real data I have some cases in which name and surname are not the same. In some of these cases, the difference is real, but in some others, the difference is just caused by misspellings. Seeing both surname and name2 in m helps to visualize the cause of the mismatch.  Please see my own answer.

And I strongly disagree with the "-1": "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" ???? In that case, how you explain that the authors of dplyr::full_join were actually noticing and fixing this problem with merge() ?

It's unclear why you would want both join columns in your output. One ill-advised option is to do a Cartesian product and then subset the rows where surname and name are equal. This isn't advised because you can exceed the computer's RAM if the data is large, but it does give the desired result for this small dataset (i.e. the name column from books is included in the output). But as mentioned, having two identical columns seems unnecessary.
merge(authors, books, by = NULL) |>
  subset(surname==name)

    surname nationality deceased     name                         title other.author
1     Tukey          US      yes    Tukey     Exploratory Data Analysis         <NA>
7  Venables   Australia       no Venables Modern Applied Statistics ...       Ripley
13  Tierney          US       no  Tierney                     LISP-STAT         <NA>
19   Ripley          UK       no   Ripley            Spatial Statistics         <NA>
24   Ripley          UK       no   Ripley         Stochastic Simulation         <NA>
30   McNeil   Australia       no   McNeil     Interactive Data Analysis         <NA>

The better option, particularly for larger datasets, is to use dplyr's join functions:
library(dplyr)
full_join(authors, books, by = c("surname" = "name"), keep = TRUE) 

   surname nationality deceased     name                         title     other.author
1    Tukey          US      yes    Tukey     Exploratory Data Analysis             <NA>
2 Venables   Australia       no Venables Modern Applied Statistics ...           Ripley
3  Tierney          US       no  Tierney                     LISP-STAT             <NA>
4   Ripley          UK       no   Ripley            Spatial Statistics             <NA>
5   Ripley          UK       no   Ripley         Stochastic Simulation             <NA>
6   McNeil   Australia       no   McNeil     Interactive Data Analysis             <NA>
7     <NA>        <NA>     <NA>   R Core          An Introduction to R Venables & Smith

The output includes all matching rows, and also the unmatching rows (#7).
For non-matches, use anti_join:
anti_join(books, authors, by = c("name" = "surname"))
    name                title     other.author
1 R Core An Introduction to R Venables & Smith

Or in base R:
subset(books, name %in% setdiff(name, authors$surname))
    name                title     other.author
7 R Core An Introduction to R Venables & Smith


In the merged dataframe m, the column surname from the authors dataframe is not retained because you are merging by this column, and it gets replaced by the column name from the books dataframe.
But you can add a name column to the m dataframe and assign a value as I did in the code below
m$name <- NA # Create a new column 'name' and initialize it with NA values
m$name[!is.na(m$surname)] <- m$surname[!is.na(m$surname)] # Copy values from 'surname' to 'name' where 'surname' is not NA
m



It's unclear why you would want both join columns in your output.

In my case, considering that some cases are present in one table but not in the other, it is important to detect those mismatches due to simple misspellings.
Therefore, modifying the example data so that we have a "Riplei" (misspeling):
    books <- data.frame(
      name = I(c("Tukey", "Venables", "Tierney",
                 "Ripley", "Riplei", "McNeil", "R Core")),
      title = c("Exploratory Data Analysis",
                "Modern Applied Statistics ...",
                "LISP-STAT",
                "Spatial Statistics", "Stochastic Simulation",
                "Interactive Data Analysis",
                "An Introduction to R"),
      other.author = c(NA, "Ripley", NA, NA, NA, NA,
                       "Venables & Smith"))
books$name2 <- books$name
m <- merge(authors, books, by.x = "surname", by.y = "name", all = TRUE)
m <- m[,c(1,6, 2:5)]

We get:
> m
   surname    name2 nationality deceased                         title     other.author
1   McNeil   McNeil   Australia       no     Interactive Data Analysis             <NA>
2   R Core   R Core        <NA>     <NA>          An Introduction to R Venables & Smith
3   Riplei   Riplei        <NA>     <NA>         Stochastic Simulation             <NA>
4   Ripley   Ripley          UK       no            Spatial Statistics             <NA>
5  Tierney  Tierney          US       no                     LISP-STAT             <NA>
6    Tukey    Tukey          US      yes     Exploratory Data Analysis             <NA>
7 Venables Venables   Australia       no Modern Applied Statistics ...           Ripley

And I can see now the problem: in my opinion, the name of the 1st variable in m ("surname") is misleading, as m[,1] is actually authors$surname and books$name combined. I was expecting m to be:
   surname    name nationality deceased                         title     other.author
1   McNeil   McNeil   Australia       no     Interactive Data Analysis             <NA>
2   R Core   R Core        <NA>     <NA>          An Introduction to R Venables & Smith
3   <NA>   Riplei        <NA>     <NA>         Stochastic Simulation             <NA>
4   Ripley   Ripley          UK       no            Spatial Statistics             <NA>
5  Tierney  Tierney          US       no                     LISP-STAT             <NA>
6    Tukey    Tukey          US      yes     Exploratory Data Analysis             <NA>
7 Venables Venables   Australia       no Modern Applied Statistics ...           Ripley

because "Riplei" does not exist in authors$surname.
Anyway, now that I know the issue, the trick of introducing a new variable (name2 in this example) is a sufficient workaround,
but what Gregor Thomas suggests:
> dplyr::full_join(authors, books, by = c("surname" = "name"), keep = TRUE)
   surname nationality deceased     name                         title     other.author
1    Tukey          US      yes    Tukey     Exploratory Data Analysis             <NA>
2 Venables   Australia       no Venables Modern Applied Statistics ...           Ripley
3  Tierney          US       no  Tierney                     LISP-STAT             <NA>
4   Ripley          UK       no   Ripley            Spatial Statistics             <NA>
5   McNeil   Australia       no   McNeil     Interactive Data Analysis             <NA>
6     <NA>        <NA>     <NA>   Riplei         Stochastic Simulation             <NA>
7     <NA>        <NA>     <NA>   R Core          An Introduction to R Venables & Smith

is the actual clean solution and the issue can be closed.

Yes - I see your point. I'm now wondering why merge does this odd behaviour. it looks like a bug... In any case, adding name2 doesn't really help (I think). Best to use full_join from dplyr.

@Edward: for using merge(), I would need both name2 and surname2 to have both keys in the output, as m$surname is actually a new variable. But dplyr::full_join() is clearly the way to go. Thanks.
